# Installing Vivado ML 2021.2 in CentOs but process is hang in 'Generating installed device list'

Tags: centos, fpga, xilinx, vivado

anybody can help me figure out why the installation is hanging on 'Generating installed device list' and how to solve it without starting the process all over. I am working on CentOs.
Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens due to following missing packages:

- `libstdc++6:i386`
- `libgtk2.0-0:i386`
- `dpkg-dev:i386`
- `ncurses5-compat-libs`
- `python3-pip`
- `libtinfo5`
- `libncurses5`

Answer (score 1):

As BKN mentioned, you need to install the missing packages.
To avoid starting all over again, you can do the following:

1. Check the log: `cat ~/.Xilinx/xinstall/*.log`
2. Locate the error message. It should look something like:

```
2022-01-09 10:53:11,458 DEBUG: n.t:? - Executing script Generating installed device list: /tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2021.2/bin/vivado [-nolog, -nojournal, -mode, batch, -source, /tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2021.2/scripts/sysgen/tcl/xlpartinfo.tcl, -tclargs, /tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2021.2/data/parts/installed_devices.txt]
2022-01-09 12:05:35,319 DEBUG: n.t:? - Unable to run GenerateDevListFileLin, exit code: 130, stdout: , stderr: application-specific initialization failed: couldn't load file "librdi_commontasks.so": libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory failure msg:
 application-specific initialization failed: couldn't load file "librdi_commontasks.so": libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-01-09 12:05:35,319 DEBUG: n.t:? - Executing script Generating installed device list for Model Composer: /tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2021.2/bin/vivado [-nolog, -nojournal, -mode, batch, -source, /tools/Xilinx/Model_Composer/2021.2/data/xmcGenBoardParts.tcl, -tclargs, /tools/Xilinx/Model_Composer/2021.2/../../Vivado/2021.2, librdi_dsp_tcltasks.so, /tools/Xilinx/Model_Composer/2021.2/data]
```

3. The log informs you exactly what the missing package is (in this case it was `libtinfo`), and also provides you with the script to run after you install the package:

```
/tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2021.2/bin/vivado -nolog -nojournal -mode batch -source /tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2021.2/scripts/sysgen/tcl/xlpartinfo.tcl -tclargs /tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2021.2/data/parts/installed_devices.txt
```

Notes:

- Make sure to use the Vivado version (here it was `2021.2`) and location (here it was `/tools/Xilinx`) according to your system.
- You may need to run the script in `sudo` if the the permissions for writing are not available in user mode.

Comment: Thanks, `sudo` usage was the most important point for me, this command can be find everywhere but I didn't see anyone mentioned that it needs root permission to work, also before running the installer it needs `sudo` too, like this: `sudo ./Xilinx_Unified_2021.2_1021_0703_Lin64.bin`

Answer (score 0):

I also encounterd this problem on Archlinux with Vivado 2018.3.

But I just installed the library `ncurses5-compat-libs`, then the problem is solved.

Perhaps you can solve this by checking the library `ncurses5-compat-libs`.

Answer (score 0):

Download the tar package instead of the self-extracting bin package

Update the java and python version
`sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip`

Install Dependencies

```
    sudo apt-get install -y libstdc++6
    sudo apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-0
    sudo apt-get install -y dpkg-dev
```

NOTE: Without ibtinfo5  the application will not start and without libncurses5 the simulation will fail

```
`sudo apt-get install -y libtinfo5 libncurses5`
```

Restart the system

Untar that Vivado package
`tar -xzvf  Xilinx_Unified_2021.2_1021_0703.tar.gz`

Locate the xsetup file in the package

Install the package in batch mode
`./xsetup --agree 3rdPartyEULA,XilinxEULA --batch Install --product "Vivado" --edition "Vivado ML Enterprise" --location "/home/USER"`

**Once the installation has been successfully completed**
Locate the settings64.sh file
`./settings64.sh`

Locate the cable drivers
`cd Vivado/2021.2/data/xicom/cable_drivers/lin64/install_scripts/install_drivers`
`./install_drivers`

**Installing Vivado Board Files**

Get the board package from the git https://github.com/Digilent/vivado-boards.git

From the vivado-board-master package copy the folder board_files undert /vivado-board-master/new/board_files

Paste the board files to Vivado/2021.2/data/boards

From the vivado-board-master package copy the file Vivado_init.tcl under /vivado-board-master/utility

Paste the file Vivado_init.tcl to the Vivado installation

That's it!! You might not need to do all these steps but that is what I ended up doing and it worked for the two machines where I installed Vivado. The installation took less than one hour.

---

This was [originally edited into the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70767297/2) by the OP.